# How Do I Get j2objc To Run With Doppl?

Tags: doppl

When I follow the instructions to get Doppl going, and I run the `dopplBuild` Gradle task, I get an error message about `j2objc` returning error code 127. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cause of this is not having a JDK available for command-line use on your development machine. While Android Studio can use its own JDK copy, that does not make `javac` and related tools available from the command line. The `j2objc` tool in the Doppl toolchain needs these tools available from the command line.

The simplest solution is to download and install a JDK, following whatever the normal practice is for doing so on your development machine's OS, such as [downloading JDK 8 from Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and installing it. If `javac` runs successfully from the command line, then try running `dopplBuild` again and see if you get past the "error code 127" result.

Comment: Also note. Old point releases of java 8 can be problematic for j2objc. It uses the java parser included with the jdk. If having issues, check your system java version.